# error reading as json

Tags: json, linux, neo4j, neoclipse

I got problems while running Neoclipse with the Neo4j community edition 2.0.0.

On a Linux machine, after connecting, Only the first node (id=1) appears, with no relationships.

I set the deep level to 4 but nothing happens. 
I also see the different relationship types on the windows but cannot navigate.

On a windows machine the situation is worse: I got an 'error reading as json' when I try to connect with the DB. (Neoclipse version is 1.9.5).

Can anyone help please?

Thank you

Paolo

Answer (score 2):

Neoclipse' source repo contains already some commits regarding Neo4j 2.0 - however there seems not to have happened a release since then. So you might checkout the sources from https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neoclipse and build it locally?